# Question mark in regular expression matching is not working

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regular expressions. I thought that this would return `matched succesfully`, but it does not. Why is that so?

```
String myString = "SUB_HEADER5_LABEL";
if (myString.matches(Pattern.quote("SUB_HEADER?_LABEL")))
{
    System.out.println("matched succesfully");
}
```

Comment: And why did you use `Pattern.quote`? Just remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Pattern.qoute()` will create a Pattern that only matches **exactly** the given String. you need

```
if (myString.matches("SUB_HEADER\\d_LABEL"))
```

If you expect the number to exceed 9, add the `+` quantifier like

```
if (myString.matches("SUB_HEADER\\d+_LABEL"))
```

if you want to match a digit where you have `?` (wich means one or zero `R` in your case, because it's a quantifier). you need to replace it with `[0-9]` or `\\d`.

Comment: After removing the Pattern.quote and replacing ? with [0-9] it worked.